# tkinter: Help fixing photo image error created when same window opened twice

Tags: python, tkinter

**I think I've pretty much narrowed down the problem, so I'll put it out here:**

I made a change to the program I am working on. The change makes a certain tkinter window reopen when an error occurs. This was done by moving it to a function, and having the script call the function if it needed to. This solved users having to restart the program.

All the windows in my program have an icon that is called and implemented in every window using the following lines:

```
Thumbnail = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\Owatch\\Pictures\\NetSendClient\\files\\GIF\\TK_ICON.gif")
    Window.tk.call("wm","iconphoto",Window._w, Thumbnail)
```

This works fine for every single window across the program. However, it continues to generate an error when the *same window is called to open a **second time**.*

**Error:**

```
File "C:\Users\Owatch\Documents\Unisung\Produced Content\NetSendClient[0.9]\files\Program_Files\NS[9].py", line 208, in SCN
    Window.tk.call("wm","iconphoto",Window._w, Thumbnail)
_tkinter.TclError: can't use "pyimage4" as iconphoto: not a photo image
```

I'm not sure why this error occurs the second time the window is opened. To give some more information on why it needs to be reopened. When a user presses a button inside this window, it triggers a function that **calls the window to be destroyed before it is later reopened**. So maybe it's because it's *not being cleanly disposed of or something*. I don't know. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem was created by a confliction between multiple windows using the same icon simultaneously.**

I cannot go any more specific than that, but the issue was resolved by *eliminating temporary and toplevel windows that did not destroy themselves before another opened.*

I hope this can be of some assistance to other individuals. I am afraid I cannot provide any more information than this.